# how to use model in laravel to get value?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 3 table Orders , Orderdetails and  products table every order is unique and every order have multiple orderdetail with order id and every orderdetail has product_id

I am using a `foreach` loop in blade

```
 @foreach($order->orderdetail as $odetail)
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="{{ $odetail->amount }}" ></td>
   </tr>
    @endforeach
```

this `value="{{ $odetail->amount }}"` gets value 25 in input field

i have another foreach loop

```
 @foreach($products as $key => $p)
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="{{ $p->order->orderdetail->unit }}"></td>
   </tr>
    @endforeach
```

**i want that above loop `value="{{ $odetail->amount }}"` output in 2nd foreach loop so i try this**

```
value="{{ $p->order->orderdetail->unit }}"
```

if orderdetail gets value in first loop then why it is not getting value in 2nd foreach loop can someone clear me what is mistake and how doeas model works and how i can get value in 2nd loop?

here is my Order model class and orderdetail function

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function orderdetail(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','order_id');
        }
}
```

and here is my orderdetail class and functions

```
class OrderDetail extends Model
{    
    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

here it is product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

databse image of orderdetai
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhf63.png)

Comment: Can you share your model's please, including the "unit" field. But a broad assumption would be that your unit field is also a relational field, hence it is not possible to output the collection directly.

Comment: please show model query form which you are fetching data

Comment: type `dd($products)` and see the records over there

Comment: Can you share the product model as well?

Comment: thanx for every contributors i have updated code with all the models which are used

Comment: There isn't any relation for `order` in the `Product` model

Comment: `$p->order->orderdetail->unit` You need to have a relation of `order` in `Product` model as well

Comment: @ZainFarooq thanx i think you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just missed the `order` relation in the `Product` model

```
public function orders(){ // by laravel convention you need a plural name for hasMany relation
    return $this->hasMany('App\order','product_id');
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: in order table i did not use order_id i only have id so when i pass hasMany('App\Order','id'); it gives me error  [orderdetail] does not exist

Comment: My bad. I have changed the answer. There should be the `product_id` instead of `order_id`